# Is this redundant pronoun use "grammatical"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is this sentence grammatically valid or not?

> People who achieve they do this with perseverance.

One of the two answers to the earlier question [Unnecessary pronouns: “The President he issued…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151795/unnecessary-pronouns-the-president-he-issued) says *clearly **it's not** "correct grammatically", as it is redundant*. The other  says *it **is** grammatical, [but it's] missing a comma [before the pronoun].*

The first of those two earlier answers has only a single upvote, and the second has none at all, so  I don't know which to believe.

Comment: What do you think is potentially right or wrong about the sentence? We can provide feedback on your reasoning or assumptions, but this is not a proofreading service.

Comment: Have you seen the [ell.se] site yet? It might be a better place to ask some of your questions. However, whether you ask here or there, more detail helps immensely.

Comment: Choster, RegDwight, if the post is off topic.. where you suggest me to post this?

Comment: @user57406 - Pay attention to the **reason** it's been listed as off-topic: _...unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified_. It's not _where_ you should ask the question, it's _how_ you should ask the question. You might want to look at some of [this user's](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119) questions; he does a good job of being very precise about the source of confusion, and including his prior research.

Comment: This is english language & usage service. That's what I'm asking choster. What should I open my writing to proof here to get theft? And one little sentence correction isn't proof reading. I hope to get solution from you, if you can't, at least let others to solve it.

Comment: This is my fb post. What source can I give you?

Comment: The sentence can be grammatical in spoken English with qualifications. E.g. 'He went on to say, "People who achieve, they do this with perseverance".'    We make it clear that it's a quote of someone speaking, and there is a comma which shows that this person posited "People who achieve" as a topic, and then commented on the topic in a clause, referring to people as "they". This is similar to "The times they are a changin'". (Title of a song by Bob Dylan, native speaker of English). It is common in some dialects. "My wife, she's a good cook", etc.

Comment: user57406 The snag is that this question has led to a reasonable part-answer by Susan Gerard, and a beautiful analysis by Kaz, with some real insight – but, if we are to judge by the poor grammar you use in your posts in this thread, you need to greatly develop your **basic** English skills before you'll be able to benefit from Kaz's answer. This is not the remit of this website – **ELL** is for people needing to correct grammar like 'This is english language & usage service. That's what I'm asking choster. What should I open my writing to proof here to get theft?'.

Comment: I believe this question was erroneously closed as "proofreading". Arguably it may be a duplicate of the earlier question to which I've just added a link, but that's another story. Certainly as things currently stand there's no single "unambiguously correct" answer easily identifiable by the votes cast for answers to either question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not quite correct.

> People who achieve they do this with perseverance.

This sentense is correct:

> People who achieve do so through perseverance.

People (who achieve) is the subject, so you do not need the pronoun *they*.

They achieve *through* (that is, by doing something), not with (in this case.)

to do (the achieving) is to *do so*; *this* is a determiner. You don't need one here.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use "they do" then any other way can make the sentence?

Comment: In fact such sentences are used by native speakers of English. They seem to occur in some dialects more, and are not appropriate  for formal writing. So it would appear that: "This answer, it is not as complete and authoritive as it is cracked up to be, you know?"