# Unnecessary pronouns: "The President he issued..."

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, redundancy

Is it now considered acceptable to follow a proper noun ... or *any* noun ... with a pronoun? E.g.

> The President he issued a new executive order.

Comment: The example you provided makes no sense. A pronoun can follow proper nouns, but there are very limited cases I can think of, like "There are five guys named Mike in my class. The Mike he saw was probably Mike Doe."

Comment: Or, _As the President, he issued a new executive order._

Comment: I agree that my example makes no sense, but I hear it and other similar uses of a noun immediately followed by the appropriate pronoun (e.g. The book, it was on the best seller list.) all of the time on cable news outlets.

Comment: This is an oral dialect form rather than more standard English. It probably would be written with a comma before *he*.

Comment: I agree that the example beginning "As president, he...." is proper, but not what I asked. Same goes for example"The Mike he saw...."

Comment: Does calling something an "oral dialect form" mean it is proper or is this another politically correct phrase?

Comment: You will need to specify "acceptible for what" before we can answer.

Comment: It's not about political correctness. It is as "proper" as when someone says, Yo! or Hey! or types *btw*, *j/k*, or *lol*.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical (when the missing comma is inserted). It would then be in the form of a *left dislocation* construction. It is part of today's standard English.

Comment: Isn't this topicalization?

Comment: CNN anchors, they do it all the time. My elementary school teachers, they are spinning in their graves.

Comment: I gave @F.E. an upvote.  This reminds me of the poetic form; "The pipes they are a'callin'" or "the times they are a'changing".  Very unusual to use this form though.

Comment: @IchabodE 'The times they are a'changing' serves both as answer and commentary.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it now considered acceptable to follow a proper noun ... or *any* noun ...  with a pronoun? E.g.
>
> - The President he issued a new executive order.

Yes, it is grammatical, and has been for a long, long time. Though, you're missing a comma:

- The president, he issued a new executive order.

Then the sentence would be in the form of a left-dislocation construction. Dislocation constructions (left and right) are part of today's standard English, and they are commonly found in informal styles and registers.

The extra noun phrase (e.g. "the president") serves as antecedent for a personal pronoun (e.g. "he"). Usually, the detached noun phrase is a rather heavy or complex expression, e.g.

- One of my cousins, she has triplets.
- The man next door, I think his car was stolen.
- This guy in my class, I gave him my notes to copy and he never returned them.

but it doesn't have to be, e.g.

- Garlic, I eat it and pretty soon my stomach's upset.

For info, there's the 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, section "Dislocation", page 255. Also there's  the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, section "Dislocation", pages 1408-14.

Answer (score 2):

AmE here.

I think the issue here is not one of acceptability, it's one of why it's done.

Clearly it's not "correct grammatically", as it is redundant, but you mention that you *hear* it. It would rarely make it into print unless it was a quote or a transcription. You would probably have a very hard time finding it even in very informal writting (such as blogs). It's like a filler word, just a thoughtlessness in speech, akin to *uh*. If I had to transcribe it, it would be

> The President **,** he issued... or, The President... he issued...

It *is* said, I hear it as well, but it's *discussion*. If you ever read transcripts of depositions (which is pertinent because legally, every utterance, even a cough, **must** be transcribed), you will see the most egregious violations of grammaticality you can imagine, as well as stupid mistakes, because we aren't taking the time to formulate well developed sentences. It's just how some people *speak*, even on television.

Comment: [Brer Rabbit, he say](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brer+rabbit+he%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22brer+rabbit+he+say%22&tbm=bks) "This is dated American dialect". But I'm not sure you can really say it's "ungrammatical" just because it includes redundancy. An awful lot of perfectly normal usages do the same.

Comment: Fair enough. It's an unnecessary redundancy. And the example you used is a good example of what a transcription would look like, because it's an attempt to capture dialect. It's like criticizing Mark Twain's understanding of grammar based on Huck Finn's or Injun Joe's speech.

Comment: We might be able to say it's "ungrammatical by association", given that my Brer Rabbit example has an unarguably incorrect verb form. As does the archetypal ["The man from Del Monte, he say 'Yes!'"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_from_Delmonte) TV ad from the 80s. I'd also note that Twain never used a comma whenever he had Huck saying [Tom he {did this or that}](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm), and a cursory search of Google Books didn't identify any latter-day revisionists trying to "improve" his version.

Comment: I appreciate the literary references, but news reporters/commentators don't enjoy literary license. My question is whether it is grammatiically correct in verbal form.

Comment: @user65757 - who judges whether they enjoy literary license? Will they be jailed for mixed metaphors, bad similes, and bungled subject-verb agreement? There is more flexibility in the spoken word. This is only appropriate. Also, today's *faux pas* may well be tomorrow's *de rigueur*.

Comment: @user67657, why are you singling out newsreaders? _Everyone_ says this sometimes—I can say with almost certainty that even you yourself do it, too. That makes it grammatically correct “in verbal form”, i.e., it makes it part of the grammatical patterns generally employed by native speakers when speaking English.

Comment: That is what worries me. this (mis)