# Is "everything it’s gonna be ok" correct in some usage form?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I have seen the phrase used (mostly by non-americans) and even on song lyrics but I am not sure if it is just a confusion. Have seen contraction commonly used is "Everything's Gonna Be Okay" but my guess is that the 's would be "is" and not "it's".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unnecessary pronouns: "The President he issued..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151795/unnecessary-pronouns-the-president-he-issued) 'Is it now considered acceptable to follow a [proper noun] with a pronoun? E.g.

The President he issued a new executive order.
Yes, it is grammatical, and has been for a long, long time. Though, you're missing a comma:

The president, he issued a new executive order.
Then the sentence would be in the form of a left-dislocation construction. ' [@F.E.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am glad to hear this! A left dislocation construction. I remember an 8th grade boy struggling to tell a story to the class: “This here one guy, he . . . “